# How do I post a tweet using javascript, twitter api and node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Ok...I'm new to this >.< 
I have my npm from github.com (node-twitterbot...whose dependency is twit)
I've looked at the twitter api..
What I'm trying to do is add an action which is post a tweet.
I can't seem to find out how to define the string for the actionName (which might be...)

```
var tweet = ("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");
```

and the actionFunction. Then I need to put it all together to post. Also, I have my instructions written below, however I'm not sure how to apply them. My actionName could be "tweet"? I have no idea how to define my actionFunction either...Can someone explain this? I NEED TO KNOW WHAT TO PUT WHERE. I have the twitterbot.js file open and ready to edit along with with all my oauth keys...access and consumer stuff. Please help anyway you can. I can paste my twitterbot.js file if that helps. Below are the instructions on the npm site reads:

Actions

In order to get your node-twitterbot to actually do something, you need to define actions. It is done through the addAction() method. It takes 2 parameters:

actionName: a string value for the name of an action
actionFunction: a function to be called when a given action is scheduled. (See below for method signature)

So our addAction method might look like this:

```
Bot.addAction("tweet", function(twitter, action, tweet) {
  Bot.tweet("I'm posting a tweet!");
});
```

The twitter variable passed into the function is the Twit object associated with a given node-twitterbot, and can be managed directly. The same Twit object is available as [TwitterBot].twitter as well.

The action variable passed into the function is the TwitterBotAction created by addAction.

And the tweet object is the tweet passed into the action (if there was one)
TwitterBotActions

addAction() returns a TwitterBotAction object.

```
var tweetAction = Bot.addAction("tweet", function(twitter, action, tweet) {
  Bot.tweet("I'm posting a tweet!");
});
```

But you will rarely need to directly hold onto the tweetAction directly. You can always get a reference to the action by calling

```
Bot.actionWithName("tweet");
```

Which will return the TwitterBotAction object, or null if the name is invalid (or the action already removed)

Again, I'm trying to put all of this together so i can post a tweet using the javascript in node.js Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Codecademy has a whole course on the twitter API, maybe that is useful to you? http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/twitter

Comment: I'll definitely try it out thanks, amenthes